# One-word substitute for "otherwise" in this context

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a substitute for "otherwise" that can be used *preceding an adjective*?

> An **otherwise** excellent student, going through a personal crisis, can see his results deteriorate drastically.

Close ones are "under other circumstances" or "in other conditions" ([Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/otherwise?s=t)), but I'm looking for something that can *precede* the adjective "excellent", and preferably one-word.

The reason is, these wordier options (that would go after "student") seem to give a more negative impact when describing the student. The one-word used before "excellent" seem to have less negative impact.

EDIT: I am looking for something short and straightforward that touches the point as used in the sentence without the dragging negativity implied in the wordier options. Not to mention one-word makes it sound smoother.
@Vocoder's suggestion is an interesting option that uses a positive-sounding word that would fit the context.

I should also add that I wanted a different word to use because the sample sentence is not of my own words but I want to convey the same meaning.

If you can think of any other words, please do share!

Much appreciated!!

Comment: It's not clear what is wrong with 'otherwise' (which fits all your criteria perfectly).

Comment: I do not doubt the use of othewise before excellent. I wanted a different word to use, since the sample sentence is not of my own words. And yes, I checked thesaurus which gave me those wordier options as the closest substitutes. You're right, I should have included in my post that I already checked it.

Comment: About "*the sample sentence is not of my own words*": answers posted here by others aren't your "own words" either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm finding it difficult to come up with a direct substitute, because *otherwise* is very well suited to that sentence. I have some suggestions that I think are *probably* inferior, or convey a different meaning that may not be appropriate, but they may be helpful in some way.

**[typically](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/typically)**

> 1. In most cases; usually.

**[ordinarily](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ordinarily)**

> most of the time; generally; usually:
>
> to the usual extent; reasonably:

Both words convey a meaning of "almost always" rather than "under other circumstances", so it becomes a question of whether that additional meaning is reasonably implied. I think that within context, it is - you're defining the ordinary/typical state (excellence) and then describing a situation that is atypical/out-of-the-ordinary and the impact it has.

Comment: Using a more positive-sounding word than "otherwise"  is a very interesting approach. It also gives the contrast of two different states that I'm looking for, without sounding too negative. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Or the similar 'usually'.

Answer (score -2):

Circumstances aside, an excellent student...

Comment: We're looking for answers that give some detail. It would definitely help to explain _why_ you think this would be a good phrasing, what connotations it has and so on.

Comment: *Extenuating circumstances aside (dyslexia, English language learners, etc.), if job hopefuls can’t distinguish between “to” and “too,” their applications go into the bin.*  You could perhaps add this as an example from https://hbr.org/2012/07/i-wont-hire-people-who-use-poo